# differentiability of $(x^2-y)y^2/(x^4+y^2)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$f(x,y)=(x^2-y)y^2/(x^4+y^2)$ for every $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and $f(x,y)=(0,0)$ on $(0,0)$.
I am trying to find out whether this function is differentiable or not.
I proved that its continuous on the origin and I have calculated the definition of derivative (using limit) for different paths but I could not prove that the function is not differentiable so I am guessing that it is but I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: What would be a strategy for proving the existence or nonexistence of a derivative?  Did you compute partial derivatives and examine the behavior in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$? Why not show what you actually did compute.  Otherwise this just looks like you want someone to solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to introduce the definition of differentiability of a function. A function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is differenctiable in $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^n$ if there exists a linear function $L:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ such that:
$$
\lim_{h\to (0,0)}\frac{\left|\left|\,f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-L(h)\right|\right|}{\left|\left|h\right|\right|}=0
$$
The matrix associated to the linear function $L$ is the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).

Then, let's calculate the Jacobian matrix of:
$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{(x^2-y)y^2}{x^4+y^2} & \text{if } (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\
0 & \text{if } (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}
$$
in $(x,y)=(0,0)$. First:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{0}{h^4}=0
$$
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{-h^3}{h^2}=0
$$

Then the Jacobian matrix in $(0,0)$ of $f$ is $J_{(0,0)}(\,f)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$, the if $L$ exists, it is $L(x,y)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y \\
\end{array}\right)=0$. Then:

\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\left|\left|\,f(x,y)-f(0,0)-L(x,y)\right|\right|}{\left|\left|(x,y)\right|\right|} &=& \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\left|\left|\,f(x,y)\right|\right|}{\left|\left|(x,y)\right|\right|}  \\
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\left|\left|\,f(x,y)-f(0,0)-L(x,y)\right|\right|}{\left|\left|(x,y)\right|\right|} &=& \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left|\frac{(x^2-y)y^2}{x^4+y^2}\,\right|\frac{1}{\left|\left|(x,y)\right|\right|}  \\
\end{eqnarray}

If we use the path $y=x$:
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\left|\left|\,f(x,y)-f(0,0)-L(x,y)\right|\right|}{\left|\left|(x,y)\right|\right|} &=& \lim_{x\to 0}\left|\frac{(x^2-x)x^2}{x^4+x^2}\,\right|\frac{1}{\left|\left|(x,x)\right|\right|}  \\
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\left|\left|\,f(x,y)-f(0,0)-L(x,y)\right|\right|}{\left|\left|(x,y)\right|\right|} &=& \lim_{x\to 0}\left|\frac{x^2-x}{x^2+1}\,\right|\frac{1}{|x|\left|\left|(1,1)\right|\right|}  \\
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\left|\left|\,f(x,y)-f(0,0)-L(x,y)\right|\right|}{\left|\left|(x,y)\right|\right|} &=& \frac{1}{\left|\left|(1,1)\right|\right|} \lim_{x\to 0}\left|\frac{x-1}{x^2+1}\,\right|  \\
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\left|\left|\,f(x,y)-f(0,0)-L(x,y)\right|\right|}{\left|\left|(x,y)\right|\right|} &=& \frac{1}{\left|\left|(1,1)\right|\right|} \neq 0  \\
\end{eqnarray}
Thus $f$ is not differentiable in $(0,0)$

Comment: It is fixed, thank you so much

Comment: thank you. it really helped.